# How do you use "<<-" (scoping assignment) in R?

Tags: r, scoping, lexical-scope, r-faq

I just finished reading about [scoping in the R intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope), and am very curious about the `<<-` assignment.

The manual showed one (very interesting) example for `<<-`, which I feel I understood. What I am still missing is the context of when this can be useful.

So what I would love to read from you are examples (or links to examples) on when the use of `<<-` can be interesting/useful.  What might be the dangers of using it (it looks easy to loose track of), and any tips you might feel like sharing.

Comment: I've used `<<- ` to preserve key variables generated inside a function to record in failure logs when the function fails. Can help to make the failure reproducible if the function used inputs (e.g. from external APIs) that wouldn't necessarily have been preserved otherwise due to the failure.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

`<<-` is most useful in conjunction with closures to maintain state.  Here's a section from a recent paper of mine:

> A closure is a function written by another function. Closures are
> so-called because they *enclose* the environment of the parent
> function, and can access all variables and parameters in that
> function. This is useful because it allows us to have two levels of
> parameters. One level of parameters (the parent) controls how the
> function works. The other level (the child) does the work. The
> following example shows how can use this idea to generate a family of
> power functions. The parent function (`power`) creates child functions
> (`square` and `cube`) that actually do the hard work.

```
power <- function(exponent) {
  function(x) x ^ exponent
}

square <- power(2)
square(2) # -> [1] 4
square(4) # -> [1] 16

cube <- power(3)
cube(2) # -> [1] 8
cube(4) # -> [1] 64
```

The ability to manage variables at two levels also makes it possible to maintain the state across function invocations by allowing a function to modify variables in the environment of its parent. The key to managing variables at different levels is the double arrow assignment operator  `<<-`. Unlike the usual single arrow assignment (`<-`) that always works on the current level, the double arrow operator can modify variables in parent levels.

This makes it possible to maintain a counter that records how many times a function has been called, as the following example shows. Each time `new_counter` is run, it creates an environment, initialises the counter `i` in this environment, and then creates a new function.

```
new_counter <- function() {
  i <- 0
  function() {
    # do something useful, then ...
    i <<- i + 1
    i
  }
}
```

The new function is a closure, and its environment is the enclosing environment. When the closures `counter_one` and `counter_two` are run, each one modifies the counter in its enclosing environment and then returns the current count.

```
counter_one <- new_counter()
counter_two <- new_counter()

counter_one() # -> [1] 1
counter_one() # -> [1] 2
counter_two() # -> [1] 1
```

Comment: Hey this is an unsolved R task on Rosettacode (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Accumulator_factory#R) Well, it was...

Comment: Would there be any need to enclose more than 1 closures in one parent function? I just tried one snippet, it seems that only the last closure was executed...

Comment: Is there any equal sign alternative to the "<<-" sign?

Answer (score 59):

It helps to think of `<<-` as equivalent to `assign` (if you set the `inherits` parameter in that function to `TRUE`).  The benefit of `assign` is that it allows you to specify more parameters (e.g. the environment), so I prefer to use `assign` over `<<-` in most cases.

Using `<<-` and `assign(x, value, inherits=TRUE)` means that "enclosing environments of the supplied environment are searched until the variable 'x' is encountered."  In other words, it will keep going through the environments in order until it finds a variable with that name, and it will assign it to that.  This can be within the scope of a function, or in the global environment.

In order to understand what these functions do, you need to also understand R environments (e.g. using `search`).

I regularly use these functions when I'm running a large simulation and I want to save intermediate results.  This allows you to create the object outside the scope of the given function or `apply` loop.  That's very helpful, especially if you have any concern about a large loop ending unexpectedly (e.g. a database disconnection), in which case you could lose everything in the process.  This would be equivalent to writing your results out to a database or file during a long running process, except that it's storing the results within the R environment instead.

My primary warning with this: be careful because you're now working with global variables, especially when using `<<-`.  That means that you can end up with situations where a function is using an object value from the environment, when you expected it to be using one that was supplied as a parameter.  This is one of the main things that functional programming tries to avoid (see [**side effects**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))).  I avoid this problem by assigning my values to a unique variable names (using paste with a set or unique parameters) that are never used within the function, but just used for caching and in case I need to recover later on (or do some meta-analysis on the intermediate results).

Comment: Thanks Tal.  I have a blog, although I don't really use it.  I can never finish a post because I don't want to publish anything unless it's perfect, and I just don't have time for that...

Comment: A wise man once said to me it is not important to be perfect - only out standing - which you are, and so will your posts be.

Also - sometimes readers help improve the text with the comments (that's what happens with my blog). 

I hope one day you will reconsider :)

Answer (score 10):

One place where I used `<<-` was in simple GUIs using tcl/tk.  Some of the initial examples have it -- as you need to make a distinction between local and global variables for statefullness.  See for example

```
 library(tcltk)
 demo(tkdensity)
```

which uses `<<-`.  Otherwise I concur with Marek :) -- a Google search can help.

Comment: Interesting, I somehow cannot find `tkdensity` in R 3.6.0.

Comment: The tcltk package ships with R: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/tcltk/demo/tkdensity.R

Answer (score 9):

On this subject I'd like to point out that the `<<-` operator will behave strangely when applied (incorrectly) within a for loop (there may be other cases too). Given the following code:

```
fortest <- function() {
    mySum <- 0
    for (i in c(1, 2, 3)) {
        mySum <<- mySum + i
    }
    mySum
}
```

you might expect that the function would return the expected sum, 6, but instead it returns 0, with a global variable `mySum` being created and assigned the value 3. I can't fully explain what is going on here but certainly the body of a for loop is **not** a new scope 'level'. Instead, it seems that R looks outside of the `fortest` function, can't find a `mySum` variable to assign to, so creates one and assigns the value 1, the first time through the loop. On subsequent iterations, the RHS in the assignment must be referring to the (unchanged) inner `mySum` variable whereas the LHS refers to the global variable. Therefore each iteration overwrites the value of the global variable to that iteration's value of `i`, hence it has the value 3 on exit from the function.

Hope this helps someone - this stumped me for a couple of hours today! (BTW, just replace `<<-` with `<-` and the function works as expected).

Comment: in your example, the local `mySum`is never incremented but only the global `mySum`. Hence at each iteration of the for loop, the global `mySum` get the value `0 + i`. You can follow this with `debug(fortest)`.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with it being a for-loop; you're referencing two different scopes. Just use `<-` everywhere consistently within the function if you only want to update the local variable inside the function.

Comment: Or use <<-- everywhere @smci. Though best to avoid globals.

Comment: As far as I understand, R is NOT scoped withing braces { }, which is different from many other languages. The scoping is within functions. So, `<<-` does not access the mySum outside of the for loop as you might expect; rather, it accesses mySum outside of the `fortest` function. In the first run, mySum did not exist outside of `fortest`, so it was created, initialized as zero, and then incremented. Each subsequent iteration of the for loop iterates the global mySum again. So, the mySum in `fortest` always stays as zero but a global mySum is created and incremented to 3.

Answer (score 5):

```
f <- function(n, x0) {x <- x0; replicate(n, (function(){x <<- x+rnorm(1)})())}
plot(f(1000,0),typ="l")
```

Comment: This is a good example of where _not_ to use `<<-`. A for loop would be clearer in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The `<<-` operator can also be useful for [Reference Classes when writing Reference Methods](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/refClass.html). For example:

```
myRFclass <- setRefClass(Class = "RF",
                         fields = list(A = "numeric",
                                       B = "numeric",
                                       C = function() A + B))
myRFclass$methods(show = function() cat("A =", A, "B =", B, "C =",C))
myRFclass$methods(changeA = function() A <<- A*B) # note the <<-
obj1 <- myRFclass(A = 2, B = 3)
obj1
# A = 2 B = 3 C = 5
obj1$changeA()
obj1
# A = 6 B = 3 C = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I use it in order to change inside `purrr::map()` an object in the global environment.

```
a = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

Say I want to obtain a vector which is c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5), that is if there is a 1, let it 1, otherwise add 1 until the next 1.

```
purrr::map(
  .x = seq(1,(length(a))),
  .f = function(x) {
    a[x] <<- ifelse(a[x]==1, a[x], a[x-1]+1)
    })
a
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: This tiny answer explains what brought me to this question--why `<-`  often does not work in purrr::map and I have to use `<<-` . Now I get it: purrr::map does its work inside a function and there only function scope applies. So, super-assignment `<<-` is required to modify variables outside of the purrr::map internal function (the `.f` argument).