# how to use lapply on multiple variable?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply, lapply

I am trying to speed my code by using lapply instead of for loop to provide functions variables in the lapply function I provide all functions variables in lapply function. but it gives me this error, what is the problem in here ?

```
Error in functionE(A[[i]],A,weight) : 
argument "weight" is missing, with no default
```

code structure :

```
weight<-weight
A<-functionB() #A is a list 
C<-lapply(1:length(A),function(i,A,weight){

if(functionE(A[[i]],A,weight)==TRUE)
    #some other functions
return(A)
    })
```

**EDIT** :actually `A` is list of graphs (for the simplicity , I lay out like that)

```
 for (i in 1:vcount(A[[1]])
    {
     #some function and if condition that needs((weight and, A))
     #there is a function which return j
      V(A[[1]])[i]$attribute2<-V(A[[1]])[j]$attribute1
     }
```

so I want to access `A`which changes in the for.

Comment: the example is just to show what the structure of the code look likes and it is not a reproducible example, I am sorry for that, I can not provide full code as it is depending on lots of functions.

Comment: Is `weight` a single value or a vector? If you are going over multiple things (i.e. your function takes two arguments that you want to loop over) you might want `mapply` instead.

Comment: @TARehman, yes it is a vector

Comment: Yes, you definitely need `mapply` then. I can't do anything else for you without a MWE.

Comment: @TARehman, sorry but what dose MWE stand for ?

Comment: Sorry, a minimal working example (you mentioned it as a reproducible example).

Comment: thanks,it resolved that specific problem.my bad I can't provide a MWE

Answer (score 1):

First of all in R variables in the global environment are visible to functions, so you don't have to pass them the way you do.

I am not entirely clear what you want to do but `apply` family of functions use your input as the first variable and other variables need to be constant (unless you are using `mapply`). You need to pass these other variables as variables in `(s/l)apply`.

```
lappy(1:length(A), function(i,A,weight){
    #whatever your function does
},A,weight)
```

in this case `i` will be alternating from 1 to length(A) while all other variables would remain whatever they were. Keep in mind that you don't really need to add `A` and `weight` at all since you can use them inside the function without passing them manually.

Comment: thanks for your answer.for every element of the list `(length(A))` I want to do some operation on, these functions need  `A `,  `weight  `and `i ` to specify which element we want to calculate for. as i serached  this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656792/can-lapply-not-modify-variables-in-a-higher-scope) said we can not alter things outside the scope of an apply function,

Comment: what if  `A ` changes in the function consider  `A `as list of list and some element will changes  in the function.

Comment: actually you can alter things outside a function with the `<<-` operator. for instance `a=1;b=1;lapply(a,function(x){b<<-x+5})` would make `b=6` outside lapply as well. you might want to write how would you do it using a `for` since I am still not exactly clear about your purpose

Comment: @OganM I'm not sure why the double ´<<´ . One is also fine.