# Difference between <- and <<-

Tags: r, lexical-scope

CASE 1:

```
rm(list = ls())
foo <- function(x = 6){
  set <- function(){
  x <- x*x}
  set()
x}
foo()
# [1] 6
```

CASE 2:

```
rm(list = ls())
foo <- function(x = 6){
set <- function(){
  x <<- x*x}
  set()
  x}
foo()
# [1] 36
```

I read that `<<-` operator can be used to assign a value to an object in an environment that is different from the current environment. It says that object initialization using `<<-` can be done to the objects that is not in the current environment. I want to ask which environment's object can be initialized using `<<-` . In my case the environment is environment of `foo` function, can `<<-`initialize the objects outside the function or the object in the current environment? Totally confused when to use `<-` and when to use `<<-`.

Comment: The operator `<<-` is sometimes called a deep assignement. It makes a variable and its value that is defined e.g., inside a function available to the entire code. It is R's analogy of a global variable definition. Since the use of global variables are often criticized, many say that using `<<-` is not good practice.

Comment: Discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator `<<-` is the parent scope assignment operator.  It is used to make assignments to variables in the *nearest* parent scope to the scope in which it is evaluated.  These assignments therefore "stick" in the scope outside of function calls.  Consider the following code:

```
fun1 <- function() {
    x <- 10
    print(x)
}

> x <- 5    # x is defined in the outer (global) scope
> fun1()
[1] 10      # x was assigned to 10 in fun1()
> x
[1] 5       # but the global value of x is unchanged
```

In the function `fun1()`, a *local* variable `x` is assigned to the value `10`, but in the global scope the value of `x` is not changed.  Now consider rewriting the function to use the parent scope assignment operator:

```
fun2 <- function() {
    x <<- 10
    print(x)
}

> x <- 5
> fun2()
[1] 10      # x was assigned to 10 in fun2()
> x
[1] 10      # the global value of x changed to 10
```

Because the function `fun2()` uses the `<<-` operator, the assignment of `x` "sticks" after the function has finished evaluating.  What R actually does is to go through all scopes outside `fun2()` and look for the *first* scope containing a variable called `x`.  In this case, the only scope outside of `fun2()` is the global scope, so it makes the assignment there.

As a few have already commented, the `<<-` operator is frowned upon by many because it can break the encapsulation of your R scripts.  If we view an R function as an isolated piece of functionality, then it should not be allowed to interfere with the state of the code which calls it.  Abusing the `<<-`  assignment operator runs the risk of doing just this.

Comment: why fun2(x) print 10 not 5? print(x) should print local value of x.

Comment: @DeepakYadav Sorry I updated my answer to remove the parameters from the example functions, which were not relevant.

Comment: `<<-` is *not* a global assignment operator. It only assigns globally if there's no existing definition of the variable being assigned in any of the parent environments.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I updated my answer.  Please share some green with me by upvoting thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `<<-` operator can be used to assign a variable to the global environment. It's better to use the `assign` function than `<<-`. You probably shouldn't need to use `<<-` though - outputs needed from functions should be returned as objects in R.

Here's an example

```
f <- function(x) {
    y <<- x * 2 # y outside the function
}

f(5) # y = 10
```

This is equivalent to

```
f <- function(x) {
    x * 2
}

y <- f(5) # y = 10
```

With the assign function,

```
f <- function(x) {
    assign('y', x*2 envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

f(5) # y = 10
```