# Passing arguments to a function in R

Tags: r, function

CASE 1:

```
x <- 10
f <- function(x){
  x <- 20
  x}
f(x)
# [1] 20
x
# [1] 10
```

I am satisfied with the output.

CASE 2:

```
x <- 10
f <- function(x){
  x <<- 20
  x}
f(x)
# [1] 20
x
# [1] 20
```

I expect the output of f(x) to be 10 not 20 because function f should return local value of x i.e. 10. I am totally confused.

CASE 3:

```
x <- 10
f <- function(x){
  x <<- 20
  x}
f(10)
# [1] 10
x
# [1] 20
```

In this case `f(10)` returns 10 not 20 as in CASE 2. What is going on?

Comment: In the second case, you assigned `20` to `x` in the **global** environment.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623856/difference-between-and)

Comment: for your study https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html

Comment: @ Pascal agreed that global value of x is 20. But the function f should return the local value of x which is 10

Comment: No, it is `20`. `x <<- 20`

Comment: That is why it is not recommended to use `<<-`.

Comment: @Pascal There can be good reasons to use `<<-` , e.g.,  in parallel computing; but I think that this goes too far here. Opinions differ on whether it is generally recommended not to use `<<- `.

Comment: @RHertel Even in parallel computing, I don't use `<<-`. But yes, it is as matter of opinion.

Comment: It appears that @DeepakYadav actually hit onto a very interesting feature of the R language.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It appears that the parameter passed to an R function is a reference to the value which was passed to it.  In other words, if the variable outside an R function which was passed in gets changed, then the *local* variable inside the function will *also* change.  Here are your cases 2 and 3 with comments:

**Case 2:**

```
x <- 10
f <- function(x) {
    x <<- 20        # global x is assigned to 20
    x               # therefore local x, which is a reference to
}                   # the x passed in, also changes
f(x)
# [1] 20
x
# [1] 20
```

**Case 3:**

```
x <- 10
f <- function(x) {
    x <<- 20        # global x is assigned to 20
    x               # but local x, which references a temporary variable having
}                   # the value of 10, is NOT changed by the global
f(10)               # assignment operator
# [1] 10            # therefore the value 10 is returned
x
# [1] 20
```

Comment: But what about the case 3. In this case why local variable is not assigned 20 as per your answer about case 2.

Comment: @DeepakYadav Because with `f(10)`, `10` is assigned locally to `x`.

Comment: @Pascal thanks for the comment but this doesn't explain it actually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Of course it does. If you have another explanation, please share.

Comment: @Tim if argument is passed by reference then the value of global variable should be 20 in case 1 but it is not the case.

Comment: No... in Case 1 you are not using the global assignment operator.  Therefore the local reference parameter `x` has a value which is unchanged.