# How to use a variable created in a function in your console

Tags: r, console

Let's say I have the following function:

```
create_X <- function() {

  x <- 14

}
```

Is there a way to give back the x variable to the console? So I can just hit x in my r console and then 14 pops up?

Comment: one way would be to use `<<-` instead of `<-` but it isn't really recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also carefully use

```
create_X <- function() {
  x <<- 14
}

create_X()
print(x)
```

About this operator, see also [How do you use "<<-" (scoping assignment) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r)

Comment: Thanks Vongo, this is what I was looking for~!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help

```
create_X <- function() {
  assign("x", 14, envir=globalenv())
}

create_X()
print(x)
#14
```