# How to write a result of function in the global environment in R

Tags: r, save, global, lapply

I have these datasets: `A <- 4, B <- 3, C <- 2`.

So I put them in a list 
`D<-list(A,B,C)` and want to apply this function:

```
s<-function(x) {
    t<-8
    x<-as.data.frame(x*t)
}

lapply(D,s)
```

when I apply the `lapply` function it just print them.

How can I make it saving the result in the global environment instead of printing them?

So the result should be `A` with value of 32 `B` with value of 24 `C` with value of 16.

Comment: It sounds like you want the [`scoping assignment arrow`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2628621/5977215)

Comment: I tried it at this point `x<<-as.data.frame(x*t)` the problem that it writes the value with name `x` instead of `A, B , C`

Comment: Would it be OK for you to store the result of `lapply` in the existing variable `D` ("overwrite it"). The single variables A, B and C will not be changed by this but using single variables without a "container" like a list makes it really difficult to apply flexible algorithms... You can access the variables then via `D$A`, `D$B` and `"D$C` which is only kinda namespace (consider it as a "full qualified variable name").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `lapply(D,s)`, use:

```
D <- lapply(D, s)
names(D) <- c("A", "B", "C")
list2env(D, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Well done, +1 (I didn't know that `list2env` replaces existing variables without a warning)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to store all your variables "straying" in the global environment in a `list` (keeps the environment clean/smaller and allows every kind of looping):

```
D <- list(A = 4, B = 3, C = 2)

s <- function(x) {
  t <- 8
  x * t   # return just the value
}

result <- lapply(D, s)
names(result) <- names(D)  # rename the results
D <- result  # replace the original values with the "updated" ones

D
D$A  # to access one element
```

Comment: I am trying to change the values in the global environment. so a data set that called `A` should be changed to `A*t`. so after applying the function I should not see the old `A <- 4` it must be the new `A<-32` and it should be separated from the `B` and `C`... maybe I misunderstood the use of `lapply`.

Comment: OK, now I understand the goal of your question. R always passes function parameter "by value" so that you can change them only locally (within the function) but variable of the caller will **not** change. This behavior is independent of `lapply`. I continue asking using comments on your question now...