# Modifying objects inside a function in r

Tags: r

I am new to R. So basically I have 2 questions:

1. In C++ we can pass objects as references to be able to return **multiple** modified objects from a function. What is equivalent way to modify multiple objects inside a function? (for example, `a` and `b` in `fyfunc`)
2. In below code, I thought since I have access to `b` inside `myfunc`, I could modify it. But apparently, it's a copy of `b`. Is there anyway to actually modify `b` inside `myfunc`?

> ```
> a <- c(1,2,3)
> b <- c(4,5,6)
>
> myfunc <- function(a) {
>   b <- b+1
>   cat(b) # prints: 5 6 7
>   a <- a+1
> }
>
> a <- myfunc(a)
> a
> b  # stil 4 5 6
> ```

Comment: Bad idea.  It's not recommended to modify objects across environments.

Comment: Don't write R code like you write C++ code. This will sure lead to hardships later. R is a functional language and functions ideally shouldn't have side-effects (change values outside their scope). Try re-thinking your design in a more functional way.

Comment: There are ways to do that like using `<<-` instead of `<-` but it's bad practice. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r

Comment: @RichScriven is the way I modify 'a' in above code the correct way to modify an abject?

Comment: @MrFlick what would be a good (and preferably concise) source for learning functional programming in R given I have some decent experience in C++?

Comment: I would just google till you find something you like. I don't have a particular recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `<<-` instead of `<-` or `assign('b', b+1, envir = globalenv())` in function myf.

`myf <- function(a) {
    assign('b', b+1, envir = globalenv())
    cat(b) # prints: 5 6 7
    a <- a+1
}`