# Can someone explain the behaviour of `<<-` assignament operator in R?

Tags: r

After some hours I found a bug in my code because an unexpected behaviour of the `<<-` assinament operator in r. I have read the documentation and browsed on internet but I still do not understand the behaviour of the operator.

Look these two functions:

```
# Define a function a_counter
a_counter  <- function(){

  i <<- i + 1
  print(i)

}
> i <- 0
> a_counter()
[1] 1
> print(i)
[1] 1
> a_counter()
[1] 2
> print(i)
[1] 2
```

```
# Define a function not_a_counter
not_a_counter  <- function(){

  i <- 0
  i <<- i + 1
  print(i)

}
> i <- 0
> not_a_counter()
[1] 0
> print(i)
[1] 1
> not_a_counter()
[1] 0
> print(i)
[1] 1
```

The first chunk of code runs as I expected, the variable `i` in both environments (function env. and global env.) are increased in each function call.

The second chunk of code is absolutely unexpected for me. The `i <<- i + 1` does not assign the value to the `i` located in the function environment, but it does so in the `i` located in the global environment. I expected both enviroments to be updated.

Comment: Your `a_counter` function, run in a clean R session, will return an error. Did you leave out a line somewhere? You probably forgot that you had already defined `i` in your global environment. I'm guessing you copy & pasted something wrong, since the function names don't match in subsequent code.

Comment: To be honest, I think you've understood and explained it pretty well. There's another question here that has a bunch of good answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2628621/210673. You question is actually likely a duplicate, but before I flag it as such, perhaps read that one and those answers and see what questions you might still have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the question you mention is too open for any kind of answer. I would like to keep this question, as here I asking for something very concrete. Anyway I will come across all the [answers](stackoverflow.com/q/2628621/210673) and find out something useful.

Answer (score 4):

In your `a_counter`, there is only one value of `i`. Not two. When a "free variable" is found in a function, it's looked up in the environment in which the function was defined. So when you call `i` in that function, it goes up to the global environment to find the value. Then when you do `<<-`, assignment doesn't happen in the function environment at all. `<<-` always starts looking in the parent environment. If you look at

```
counter_vars  <- function() {
  a <- 4 
  i <<- i + 1
  ls() 
}
counter_vars()
# [1] "a"
```

you'll see that the only variable inside the function environment/closure is the `a` variable. The `i` variable doesn't exist there. So with the original function all the `i`s come from global scope

```
a_counter  <- function(){    
  i <<- i + 1    # global i = global i + 1
  print(i)       # global i still (no local variable has been created)
}
```

So the behavior you see in `not_a_counter` should be expected because `<<-` will not change values in current environment. It always start looking one environment "up". When you have

```
not_a_counter  <- function(){    
  i <- 0         # local i (always 0)
  i <<- i + 1    # global i == local i + 1 (always 0+1)
  print(i)       # local i (always still 0, local value not changed)
}
```

The `i` variable is no longer "free" once you define it in the function. So `i <- 0` creates a local variable, in the `i <<- i + 1` part, the right hand side `i+1` uses that local variable and assigns to the `i` in the parent environment.