# What does the operator "<<-" do when used to alter dataframes inside user-defined functions?

Tags: r

When I'm writting a function that creates new dataframes from previously existing ones, how is using "<<-" different from using "<-" or "="?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html

Comment: There is *a lot* of very useful information in the linked post. Please take a look.

Comment: Also relevant: [How do you use “<<-” (scoping assignment) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r)