# is it possible to have an invisible function in R?

Tags: r, function

I want to distribute an R object that is a function. For instance, say, here is my function:

```
f <- function(x) (x * x)
save(f, file = "f.rda")
```

Then,

```
load("f.rda")
```

gives me the function 'f', however, when I type

```
f
function(x) (x * x)
```

Is it possible to have this function f, but to hide what is in the source code.

I guess in some sense, I am probably asking for an equivalent to the pre-compiled "binary object file" without the source code.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I am not sure that this is necessarily possible.

Comment: Try `invisible(f)`

Comment: so, save it as that?

Comment: Yes try and run <https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/invisible>

Comment: My apologies, I do not quite understand how this will work. Can you give me an example using my function. To clarify, I want the f to do the calculation, but the source not  to be available. I have looked at invisible earlier, but I did not figure out how to make it work for my case.

Comment: @user2864740, can you give me a simple example? I can not quite figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to use a local environment / closure to do this. The following code uses a [scoping assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2628621/2864740) to expose f.

```
local({
g <- function (x) x * x; # "secret" algorithm!
f <<- function (x) g(x);
})

# g is not in scope here, although it is still bound in f's closure
f(4) # => 16
```

The result of `print(f)` only covers f itself only, and not the "secret" in g:

```
function (x) g(x)
```

This naturally won't hide the original file source or textual content itself.

As I don't actually use R, I've no idea if the environment can be reflected<sup>1</sup> to still expose g (and at some level it must be possible as a .rda file can be generated). However, this approach appears to fulfill the original requirement of not *immediately* exposing the algorithm.

<sup>1</sup>As @HongOoi points out, the reflected environment (and g) can be accessed with `environment(f)$g`, which once again would expose the "secret".

Comment: `environment(f)$g`

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks - so enough to make looking a "purposeful intent" then.

Comment: @HongOoi, thank you! Very illustrative and nicely done. Though still retrievable, perhaps still useful.

Comment: Sorry, meant to thank @user2864740 for the code, but thanks also to HongOoi for the help.