# rlang::duplicate data.table::copy work outside a function but not inside

Tags: r, rlang

New to R. I'm trying to conditionally duplicate a function inside another function. I've tried using rlang::duplicate and data.table::copy.

```
library(rlang)

func1 <- function() {
        print("horg1")
    }
func2 <- function() {
    print("horg2")
}

cond.rename <- function(horg) {
    if (horg=="1") {
            func<-rlang::duplicate(func1)
    }
        
    if (horg=="2") {
            func<-rlang::duplicate(func2)
    }
    
    func
}

cond.rename("1")
```

This does not work. No function called "func" is created. However, if I run `func<-duplicate(func1)` outside of a function it will create the function called "func". What am I doing wrong? If it's not obvious, this is drastically simplified from my actual code so if the purpose of the whole thing isn't clear that is why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rename_*()` function can do one of two things.  `rename_local()` returns a function (not a value) that you can then call.

```r
func1 <- function() {
  print("horg1")
}
func2 <- function() {
  print("horg2")
}

rename_local <- function(horg) {
  if (horg == "1") {
    func <- rlang::duplicate(func1)
  } else if (horg == "2") {
    func <- rlang::duplicate(func2)
  }

  func
}

# Return functions
rename_local("1")
#> function() {
#>   print("horg1")
#> }
rename_local("2")
#> function() {
#>   print("horg2")
#> }

# Return values
rename_local("1")()
#> [1] "horg1"
rename_local("2")()
#> [1] "horg2"
```

And `rename_global()` overwrites the function in the global environment.  If you want to (re)define a function in the global environment, use `<<-` instead of `<-`.  This is sometimes called [super assignment](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#super-assignment--)

```r
rename_global <- function(horg) {
  if (horg == "1") {
    func <<- rlang::duplicate(func1)
  } else if (horg == "2") {
    func <<- rlang::duplicate(func2)
  }
}

# Set global function
rename_global("1")
func
#> function() {
#>   print("horg1")
#> }
```

Resources for Environments.

- The [chapter in *Advanced R*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html) by Hadley.
- The [Scope](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope) section of the [Intro manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) is another good source.
- [How do you use "<<-" (scoping assignment) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630222/1082435)

Comment: Hm, it still doesn't work for me. My end goal is to have a function named "func" in my environment.

Comment: Edited my question to clarify I do call in the library first, and other changes of yours

Comment: Huh.  ...and same error using my exact code?  Try restarting the R session?

Comment: I did restart the session and used your exact code. There's no error, it just doesn't create the "func" in my environment. Yours creates a new function called "func"?

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to write to the environment "outside" the rename function.  The response now include both approaches.