Issue with ggsave not printing diagonal histograms even thought visible in the Plots window of RStudio
A few years ago asked a question about coloring the diagonal histograms on a ggpair pairs plot using the code below ... has been working nicely for me since with that help from Stackoverflow experts.  A copy of that example code is re-produced below.
require(GGally)

# function for scatter plots with smoothed trend line
lower_plots <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(color = "black", shape = 1, size = 1, alpha = 1) +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam",...) 
} 

# working with a trick of global assignment
diag_plots <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  # increase counter each run globally so outside the function as well and this does the trick!
  x <<- x + 1
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    # choose color by counter and send bin width argument in
    geom_histogram(fill = clrs[x], ...)
} 

# set the color and counter
clrs <- c("red","green","blue","orange")
x <- 0

# pairs plot
ggpairs(iris,1:4, 
        diag = list(continuous = wrap(diag_plots, bins = 15)),
        lower = list(continuous = wrap(lower_plots, color="red", se=FALSE))) +
  theme_light(base_size = 12) + 
  theme_light(base_size = 12) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2.5,2.5,2.5,3.5), "lines"))

The results in the Plots window of RStudio is as below

However when I output the image to jpeg using the following code:
ggsave(filename = "iris.JPG",  device = "jpeg", 
       width = 22, height = 18, units = "cm", dpi = 300)

The resulting file created does not show the diagonal histograms ...

I'm looking for suggestions as to why this should be so ... worked fine about 6 months ago last time I used this bit of code in anger.  I just upgraded R to version 4.4.0 today.

You have to reset the global counter variable x to 0 before printing or saving ..., i.e. use x <- 0; ggsave(...).

Stefan thanks for this clue ... after a bit of trial and error I found the syntax "x <<-0" was required to get it to work (as used in the "diag_plots" function).   I don't really understand why this is needed but it appears to have something to do with this Q&A "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r".  If you or some other contributor could shed some light on the reasoning here that would be help.  It seems to be something related to lifetime of variables that I run into in CMD scripting from time to time.

As I was reading your question, my first thought was "lazy evaluation problem".  Your solution suggests that it is.  But why it should be triggered by an upgarde to R4.4.0, I have no idea.  I'd have expected it never to have worked...

This now works with clues provided today, albeit I'm not entire sure why the line "x <<- 0" is required.
require(GGally)

# function for scatter plots with smoothed trend line
lower_plots <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(color = "black", shape = 1, size = 1, alpha = 1) +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam",...) 
} 

# working with a trick of global assignment
diag_plots <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  # increase counter each run globally so outside the function as well and this does the trick!
  x <<- x + 1
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    # choose color by counter and send bin width argument in
    geom_histogram(fill = clrs[x], ...)
} 

# set the color and counter
clrs <- c("red","green","blue","orange")
x <- 0

# pairs plot
ggpairs(iris,1:4, 
        diag = list(continuous = wrap(diag_plots, bins = 15)),
        lower = list(continuous = wrap(lower_plots, color="red", se=FALSE))) +
  theme_light(base_size = 12) + 
  theme_light(base_size = 12) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2.5,2.5,2.5,3.5), "lines"))

x <<-0                                                        
ggsave(filename = "iris.JPG",  device = "jpeg", 
              width = 22, height = 18, units = "cm", dpi = 300)

